# Geometric interpretation of convolution?

Tags: complex-numbers, convolution, visualization

The Internet has lots of nice visualizations for the convolution of two real-valued functions. But say I have two functions $f, g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ with period $1$, and say that their convolution is another function with period $1$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$,
$$
(f \ast g)(t) = \int_0^1 f(\tau)g(t-\tau) \, d\tau.
$$
Is there any way to interpret the loop traced out by $f\ast g$ in the plane in terms of those traced by $f$ and $g$?